# How to make a round Progress Bar in codename one?

Tags: java, graphics, codenameone

I want to create a round progress bar, depicting the current status in percent in its mid. like this:

[image: round prog bar]

now I already followed the instructions on creating a [flat progress bar](http://codenameone.blogspot.de/2008/05/progress-indicator-threads-in-lwuit.html), but as I am not familiar with swing and I don't have any clue of Javas graphics, I have no clue how to transfer from the 'flat' to the 'round' progress bar.

**How could a code similiar to the progress bar look like?**

ps: I saw Hannahs post on the analog clock and tried it like this - but failed due to my lack in painting (and maybe mathematical) skills.

pps: **I don't use the GUIBuilder at all** (bare bones)

ppps: I want it to be drawn (if possible), not image-based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it but something like this should work:

```
Container progress = new Container(new LayeredLayout());
Label percent = new Label("0%");
percent.getUnselectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
progress.add(new Label(progressOverlayImage, "Container")).
        add(FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(percent));
progress.getUnselectedStyle().setBgPainter((Graphics g, Rectangle rect) -> {
    g.setColor(0xff0000);
    g.fillArc(progress.getX(), progress.getY(), progressOverlayImage.getWidth(), progressOverlayImage.getHeight(), 0, currentProgress360);
});
```

You will need the following to get this to work.

- You will need to update the percentage label when changing the progress value
- You will need an "overlay image" that is transparent where you want the progress to appear
- You will need a variable called `currentProgress360` that will represent the current state of progress between 0 and 360

Comment: It _kind of works_ . How can I make the progressOverlayImage scale?
And the progress itself is an oval, but I need a circle... how to?

Comment: And I just found another problem: Your solution is filling the exact opposite of what I want filled; I want the arc to be filled - but it is currently filling everything but the arc - or did I enter the wrong image? Meaning: do I need to put an image showing the arc of the circle  as progressOverlayImage, or should I use one showing the edges and leaving the arc open?

Comment: I fixed the arc to draw in the size of the image. Your image needs to be transparent only in the area where you want the arc filled so it probably is the opposite of what I was talking about.