# Build Server: 'Error! Failed to transfer some classes!'

Tags: codenameone, build-server

I wanted to test my App on my phone, so I send it to the Build server (Android). Instead of the expected, successfull build, I got an error:

```
Error! Failed to transform some classes
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.private.container.projectDetailsContainer.top.center.progCircle.ProgressCircle
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.BackportLambdaInvocations.loadClass(BackportLambdaInvocations.java:116)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.BackportLambdaInvocations.access$100(BackportLambdaInvocations.java:16)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.BackportLambdaInvocations$InvokeDynamicInsnConverter.backportLambda(BackportLambdaInvocations.java:101)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.BackportLambdaInvocations$InvokeDynamicInsnConverter.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(BackportLambdaInvocations.java:94)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1452)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1017)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:693)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:506)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Transformers.lambda$transform$4(Transformers.java:106)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Transformers$$Lambda$8/636718812.accept(Unknown Source)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Transformers.transform(Transformers.java:120)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Transformers.transform(Transformers.java:106)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Transformers.backportClass(Transformers.java:46)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Retrolambda.run(Retrolambda.java:72)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.private.container.projectDetailsContainer.top.center.progCircle.ProgressCircle
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.NonDelegatingClassLoader.loadClass(NonDelegatingClassLoader.java:27)
    at net.orfjackal.retrolambda.lambdas.BackportLambdaInvocations.loadClass(BackportLambdaInvocations.java:114)
    ... 14 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Notice**

- I already used the App on my mobile device and there was no problem with it
- The App has no problems running in the simulator

**EDIT 1**

As you asked for it, here is the way I use the class (the only time I use it):

```
package com.companyname.mobile.container.projectDetailsContainer.top.center.progCircle;

import java.util.HashMap;

import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.GridLayout;
import com.companyname.mobile.renderer.projectListitem.ProjectListItem;

public class ProgressCircleContainer extends Container {
    /*      attributes      */
    private ProgressCircle progressCircle;
    /************************/

    /**
     * Constructor for the Container. 
     * The given parameter is the clicked listitem 
     * 
     * @param clicked List item clicked by the user
     */
    public ProgressCircleContainer (ProjectListItem clicked) {
        this.clicked = clicked;
        init();
    }

    /*
     * initializes the layout of the container
     */
    private void init () {

        this.layout = new GridLayout (2);
        /*      left container      */
        progressCircle = new ProgressCircle(clicked.getStatus());
        leftCont = new Container ();
        leftContLayout = new BorderLayout();
        leftCont.setLayout(leftContLayout);
        leftCont.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, progressCircle);
        /****************************/
        this.add(leftCont); //using gridlayout for the form
    }

    /*      Getter and Setter   */
}
```

The class is much larger, but I left out the unnessecary parts of it.

Here is the ProgCircle class:

```
package com.companyname.mobile.container.projectDetailsContainer.top.center.progCircle;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.codename1.ui.Component;
import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Graphics;
import com.codename1.ui.Image;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.FlowLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.ui.Graphics;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.Rectangle;

/**
 * This class partly draws and partly displays the round progress circle
 * one can see in the north of ProjectDetailsForm.
 * 
 * It uses a LayeredLayout to paint the progress as a circle in the background
 * while concealing the unnecessary part of it with a picture. On the GlassPane 
 * layer, there is a label showing the progress in percent
 * 
 * {@http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841377/how-to-make-a-round-progress-bar-in-codename-one}
 *
 */
public class ProgressCircle extends Container {
    /*      attributes      */
    private Label percent;
    private LayeredLayout layout;
    /************************/

    /*      constants       */
    public static final String ROUND_PROG_BAR = "roundprogbar.png";
    /************************/

    /**
     * Constructor for the round progress bar.
     * The parameter given is the color it will be drawn in.
     *
     * @param statusColor color the progress will be drawn in
     */
    public ProgressCircle (int statusColor) {
        layout = new LayeredLayout();
        this.setLayout(layout);

        try {
            Resources s = Resources.open("/theme.res");
            Image progressOverlayImage = s.getImage(ROUND_PROG_BAR);
            int currentProgress360 = 100;
            percent = new Label (String.valueOf((int) (((double)currentProgress360 /360)*100))+ "%");
            percent.getUnselectedStyle().setFgColor(0x000000);

            percent.getUnselectedStyle().setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
            this.add(new Label (progressOverlayImage.scaled((int)(progressOverlayImage.getWidth()*0.65), (int)(progressOverlayImage.getHeight()*0.65)), "Container")).

                add(FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(percent));
            this.getUnselectedStyle().setBgPainter((Graphics g, Rectangle rect) -> {
                g.setColor(statusColor);
                g.fillArc(this.getX(), this.getY(),(int)(progressOverlayImage.getWidth()*0.65), (int)(progressOverlayImage.getHeight()*0.65), 0, currentProgress360);
            });



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Another notice:**
I was wondering if it could be the too long package name. I replaced my companies name by 'companyname', but their length is equal.

If you need further information, let me know.

If it does not compile like this, I may have deleted a nessecary part, but then it is my fault right now. **The app compiles successfully in the simulator and is fully functioning**

**EDIT 2:**

here a link to the full error:
http://pastebin.com/ktCAbxk5

Comment: When you say you're already using the app on a mobile device, did you build that working version with the build server also?  What has changed since your successful build?  Did you make changes to your project?  How long ago was the successful build?  If we can narrow down what has changed, it will help to point out the problem.

Comment: Ugh.. yes, I build it with the default build server of cn1 and there was about a week in between.
Sure I made some major changes - The App ain't that big yet, so I would say there were about 1500 (+-200) lines of code added within this week (I take the logging thing pretty serious, solely logging is an additional ~500 lines maybe).
Normally I uninstall the app during the build session of the server, so unfortunately I don't have the old build. As I recall, I seem to have added some pictures, a lot of Container and plain old java files and some pictures. And this: (following comment)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841377/how-to-make-a-round-progress-bar-in-codename-one/35858530?noredirect=1#comment59428909_35858530

Comment: If you can't think of anything that could have gone wrong, I could check the git tree on monday (work). Simply let me know @stevehannah

Comment: @stevehannah the 'ProgressCircle' class (see the link), that was written by Shai works just fine in the simulator and I wanted to test on my device. And then there was this weird error telling me it could not be found...

Comment: Try to focus on uses of the `com.private.container.projectDetailsContainer.top.center.progCircle.ProgressCircle` related to lambda expressions that you have changed in the past week.  E.g. Lambda expressions that take this class as a parameter.

Also, try doing a "clean" build.  i.e. clean then build.  Then send the android build. 

Are you using any cn1libs in your project?

Comment: I just tried building an app containing that block of code and it worked for me on the standard Android build. I think we need some more information or a test case.

Comment: What info do you need? I could show you how I called it. But i thought of something else, could the package name be too long?

Comment: @stevehannah added an edit

Comment: @shaialmog added an edit

Comment: I just tried and placed this exact code in my sources with the exact same package name. Build passed without a problem. Is it possible you created the project as a Java 5 project and manually changed it to Java 8 without adding the java 8 build hint?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Indeed, I manually set java to 8, but I added the build hint. see here: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4294/aj3p7v8v_png.htm

Comment: And I made every single step of your 'java 8 support' page

Comment: I just tried to simply remove the files related to this error and send another android build. This time it's the same error with a different class...

Comment: Whatever class I remove, there is alway another one 'missing' according to the build server.

Comment: Open the codenameone_settings.properties and make sure the entry for the `java.version` doesn't include any spaces or special characters there. It should look exactly like this with no spaces etc. `codename1.arg.java.version=8`

Comment: @ShaiAlmog See the whole file here:

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4295/ci3xjadx_png.htm

Comment: Can you isolate this into a test case that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I could upload the project to github or bitbucket and send an invitation to you. As I have no clue what is going wrong, I can't replicate it.

Comment: When I simply copy-pasted the src folder into a new project, the problem seems to be gone and the build succeeds.

Comment: Its working now, so I really need to say thank you, but nonetheless it was strange.

Comment: I'm guessing that something went wrong when you converted the project to Java 8 but I can't see what. Maybe one of the Eclipse compiler flags?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe a bug in eclipse, maybe in CN1 - I do not know, but it solved itsself, so thats okay..

Answer (score 1):

Have you modified your project class path in any way (eg added any jars or other source dirs)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class within the package `com.private`?

`private` is a reserved word in Java so I'm actually very surprised this works for you anywhere.

Comment: That package name does not exist, there is my company name, sry for misunderstanding.